# Why can't modules be imported in standard JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I need to use a Javascript library (https://unpkg.com/troika-3d-text@0.19.0/dist/textmesh-standalone.esm.js?module) which is only delivered as a module.
When I try to import the class *TextMesh* in my non-module script *build.js*, the console gives me that error-message:

> Cannot use import statement outside a module

So I needed to make *build.js* a module. But I have many non-module scripts, which are dependant from that *build.js*, which now also need to become modules. And I have many other non-module scripts, which are dependant from them, which then also need to become modules. And so on, ...

Where is my misunderstanding of the concept of JavaScript modules, because it can't be the intent of modules, that all scripts which are (in)directly dependant from that 'first' module, must become a module, too?!

Comment: The scripts you speak of, they are not modules, are they?

Comment: You must link your script with the `type="module"` attribute, before using the import or export statement.

Comment: You must tell the browser that the script is a module by using the `type="module"`

Comment: @JayCodist: exactely - I adapted my question, thx!

Comment: @Fritzdultimate: thx, I know how to import a module. But my question is more general.

Comment: Oh, I see @Fritzdultimate

Comment: If your other scripts depend on *build.js*, and your *build.js* depends on *textmesh.esm.js*, I would not call them "independent".

Comment: "*which is only delivered as a module*" - well, then you have to transpile it yourself if you don't want to use ES6 module syntax

Comment: Have you tried import * ??  from the module name

Comment: @Bergi thx! I made a mistake: I wanted to write they are 'dependant' - I edited my question accordingly. With 'transpile' you mean: make the original module a non-module script?

Comment: @it-freelancer-magazin.de Yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [dynamic `import()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports) even in non-module scripts:

```js
(async()=>{
const { TextMesh } = await import("https://unpkg.com/troika-3d-text@0.19.0/dist/textmesh-standalone.esm.js?module");
console.log( TextMesh );
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

You must tell the browser that the script is a module by using the `type="module"` attribute e.g

`<script src="source_url" type="module"></script>`

Comment: thx, I know how to import a module. But my question is more general.